# get multiple columns within a map: rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I've a DF that I'm explicitly converting into an RDD and trying to fetch each column's record. Not able to fetch each of them within a map. Below is what I've tried:

```
val df = sql("Select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 from tableName").rdd
```

The resultant df becomes the member of `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]`

Now I'm trying to access each element of this RDD via:

```
val dfrdd = df.map{x => x.get(0); x.getAs[String](1); x.get(3)}
```

The issue is, the above statement returns only the data present on the last transformation of map i.e., the data present on `x.get(3)`. Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last line is always returned from the `map`, In your case `x.get(3)` gets returned.

To return multiple values you can return `tuples` as below

```
val dfrdd = df.map{x => (x.get(0), x.getAs[String](1), x.get(3))}
```

Hope this helped!